# How Can I get Most popular products from order table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have my orders table like these

```
 Id  | Order_id | item_id | restaurant_id | price
--------------------------------------------------
  1 |  1        |  1      |   2            | 200
---------------------------------------------------
  2 |  2         |  1      |  2             | 200
---------------------------------------------------
  3 |  3        |  2       |  2             | 400
```

How can I get popular  items from orders table in ascending order where restaurant_id is 2. 
I want something like these
Popular items

```
1 
2
```

I try but I only get total counts and I am stuck over there

```
SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM `item_orders` WHERE restaurant_id = 1
```

Comment: On which parameter you are deciding the popularity of any item? I mean it's just count or any other value? If it's count then you can just use group by in descending order of count.

Comment: based on item_id

Comment: So instead of count use Sum()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you get the count for each item and order them by count

```
SELECT  item_id, COUNT(*)
FROM    `item_orders`
WHERE   restaurant_id = 1
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Why Limit to 2 only?

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
select * from 
(SELECT COUNT(item_id) as count FROM `item_orders` 
WHERE restaurant_id = 1) as T 
order by `count` asc
```

Comment: You should format your code as code by selecting it and clicking the curly braces symbol (`{}`) in the top bar of your editor.